# How to change view of desktop popups?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, settings

How I can change the color or view of desktop popups in Ubuntu 13.10?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and paste these lines one after one

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

Then open notifyosdconfig & there you can configure it.

Credit Goes to [Webupd8 Peolple](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html)

Comment: I tried this, I installed it completely and run it in Ubuntu 13.10 anything looks ok but..when I try to apply any change, it really doesn't work! same view and same! Maybe it's not compatible with 13.10